# Who initiates Leader Election

Tags: java, algorithm

Who initiates the leader election in a peer to peer network with no leader?.
    Here is some code that i implemented when receiving messages.

```
if (message.startsWith(ELECTION)) {
        int recievedID = Integer.parseInt(ripMessage(ELECTION, message));
        if (processID > recievedID) {
            sendToAll(ELECTION + processID);
        } else if (processID < recievedID) {
            sendToAll(ACKNOWLEDGE);
        }
    } else if (message.startsWith(ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
        ackRecv++;
        if (connections.size() == ackRecv) {
            connection.sendMessage(LEADER + processID);
            this.isLeader = true;
            this.leaderID = processID;
            ackRecv = 0;
        }
    } else if (message.startsWith(LEADER)) {
        int recievedID = Integer.parseInt(ripMessage(LEADER, message));
        this.leaderID = recievedID;
        this.isLeader = false;
    }
```

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_algorithm, also likely overkill for P2P cases... still may be useful as list of issues you need to address.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think you should rephrase this as an answer (use the Paxos consensus algorithm) and include the link.  I would upvote :-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible for every peer to initiate leader election when a leader is needed?

Comment: @JimGarrison posted as answer...

Answer (score 2):

Normally in a peer-to-peer system, there would be no leader.

In such cases leader election does not make sense.

There are various peer-to-peer algorithms - for example [Chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28peer-to-peer%29).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Paxos consensus algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_algorithm). The algorithm itself likely overkill for P2P cases... still may be useful as list of issues you need to address.

Super short version - most of participants (quorum) must agree on election message {leader, version} with highest version. Multiple rounds may be necessary if multiple elections started at about the same time.